# Azure Data Factory removing spaces after column names of csv file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I have a list of CSV files with the same columns, but some have column names with spaces after them. When transferring records to the database, I face errors with columns that have spaces after the column name.

"I attempted to remove something using DataFlow, but I am unsure of how to do it."

Comment: Spaces in or around column names is always a bad idea

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is.. Do you mean the csv files have spaces around the header names and you want to remove these spaces in the csv files? Please, open one of these csv files in **Notepad**. Copy the first 3 or 4 lines and next [edit] your question and paste that in there so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: @vamsi you should try to add samples of the columns that you're working with so that the community can have a better understanding of the problem you are having. If you are getting an error, post the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use selects transformation and rule-based mapping to remove spaces from column names.

[image]

Here Is my sample data it contains `_`  in last of column name to replace it take select transformation and rule-based mapping.

[image]

```json
matching condition : true()
Column name expression : replace($$,' ','') --in you case
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, you may also take a look at the below article too, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/adf-synapse-analytics-replace-columns-names-using-rule-based/ba-p/4039551 where we discuss exactly the same scenario.